# Groupby with boolean condition True in one of the columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataframe which I want to use groupby

```
Value           Boolean1        Boolean2
 5.175603       False           False
 5.415855       False           False
 5.046997       False           False
 4.607749       True            False
 5.140482       False           False
 1.796552       False           False
 0.139924       False           True
 4.157981       False           True
 4.893860       False           False
 5.091573       False           False
 6              True            False
 6.05           False           False
```

I want to use `groupby` with `Boolean1 and Boolean2` column. The `groupby` continues from `False` to unless it finds `True` and it checks in both column and then next False to True again. If there is nomore True, then it can ignore rest of the False (values corresponding to it) or it can be there

I want to achieve similar to this.

```
Value       Boolean1            Boolean2
```

This is one group

```
 5.175603       False               False
 5.415855       False               False
 5.046997       False               False
 4.607749       True                False
```

This is another one

```
5.140482        False               False
 1.796552       False               False
 0.139924       False               True 
4.157981        False               True
```

And this is another one

```
 4.893860       False               False
 5.091573       False               False
 6              True                False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My idea is check `False`s in both columns before at least one `True` column:

```
#chain condition together by OR and invert
m = ~(df['Boolean1'] | df['Boolean2'])
#get consecutive groups with AND for filter only Trues 
#(because inverting, it return False in both cols)
s = (m.ne(m.shift()) & m).cumsum()

for i, x in df.groupby(s):
    print (x)

dtype: int32
      Value  Boolean1  Boolean2
0  5.175603     False     False
1  5.415855     False     False
2  5.046997     False     False
3  4.607749      True     False
      Value  Boolean1  Boolean2
4  5.140482     False     False
5  1.796552     False     False
6  0.139924     False      True
7  4.157981     False      True
       Value  Boolean1  Boolean2
8   4.893860     False     False
9   5.091573     False     False
10  6.000000      True     False
    Value  Boolean1  Boolean2
11   6.05     False     False
```

**Detail**:

```
print (m)
0      True
1      True
2      True
3     False
4      True
5      True
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10    False
11     True
dtype: bool

print (s)
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     3
9     3
10    3
11    4
dtype: int32
```